# Install from live USB on new Intel NUC errors out

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, intel-nuc

I've just got a brand new Intel [NUC8I7HNK](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/126141/intel-nuc-kit-nuc8i7hnk.html) NUC (along with 32GB RAM and a 1TB Intel SSD NVMe) and would like to install ubuntu on it. Since the disk is completely new it does not have anything installed.

From another Ubuntu PC I downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS iso (and validated the checksum) and created a live Ubuntu USB stick using the "Startup Disk Creator" utility, plugged in the USB in the NUC, and booted it. I could select the language, the keyboard, minimum installation, and third-party drivers with secure boot.

When the partitions were going to be created I got an error (don't remember which one). I went back and tried several times selecting or deselecting secure boot, but still got an error and could not continue. It kept coming back to the manual partitions creation.

Then I decided to reboot and see if I'd have better luck. But I've never managed to boot the live usb again! Instead I always get:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi -Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi -Not Found
Failed to start MokManage: Not Found
Something has gone serious wrong:import_mok_state() failed
: Not Found
```

When I boot the NUC without USB I simply get `A bootable device has not been detected.`

I've tried going into the BIOS and disabling Secure Boot (as suggested in one of the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098758/help-with-dual-booting-from-a-bootable-usb-or-disk)), but it still didn't help. I've also tried to reformat the USB stick and recreate it, but no change.
So it seems that something has changed on the NUC that prevents it from booting the live usb.

What else should I try?

Update:

The linked question (that is also referred when marking this question as duplicate) covers the case when one has dual-boot and ubuntu already installed. The accepted answer suggests to copy on of the .efi files when booting with a live USB. My problem is that I can't event boot the live USB! And I can't change the live usb as it's read only. So my question is what I should do next?

Comment: Have you validated your media?  (ie. confirm download of ISO & write to media was flawless using the 'check disk for defects' option)

Comment: I didn't, but I still managed to boot the live usb the first time. Doesn't the count as a validation?

Comment: @bangnab Also, you can boot with a partially corrupted ISO image made into a LiveUSB, so, it needs verification. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 explains how to verify the ISO using its checksum. Please advise if you have done so, by clicking [edit] and confirming that in the body of your question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: If you don't want to validate your media, you can always check the logs and ensure no squashfs errors occur, otherwise invalid media shows itself only as problems that can be intermittent or tiny glitches you may not even notice (a few pixels are wrong). They may only show up during certain operations (usually installs where nearly all of media is read, and less so in quick 'live' sessions).  Validation is far easier than the alternative problem solving or log checking..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the hard drive on the NUC was corrupted in some way.

I succeeded installing Ubuntu with the following:

- downloaded Fedora's iso
- Restored that image on the USB drive
- started the NUC with the fedora USB drive, that worked!
- During the fedora installation I could see that some partitions had been created. I deleted all those and created new ones
- Fedora installation went through and could reboot into that
- Restored ubuntu iso image to the USB drive (from PC)
- Started the NUB with the ubundu USB drive, now it worked also!
- Installation went through without problems

Comment: Thanks a lot, the Fedora-Image did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this device for to install Hackintosh. I think your problem maybe is related to the graphic drivers. I heard people having problems because of the Vega drivers. I think you should try installing the latest Ubuntu distro.

Check if there is a newer one. I already check it, there is a 19.04 version. Try this one

Good luck

Regards